# How do I create a variable that does not get updated in this loop?

Tags: php, html

I'm not really sure how to phrase this question, but I am trying to create a loop that outputs the dates to create a calendar, so far this works fine. The part that I am unsure how to fix is that I want the user to be able to click on a date inside of the calendar, which will take them to a new html page with more information about that day.

To do this I need to be able to post the date that they clicked on to the next page, but the issue is that the date variable is overwriting itself every time the code loops, so it only ever links to the most recent date...
Does anyone have any alternative ideas? Its probably very simple but i'm new to this so please go easy on me :)

```
    for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
        if (($i - $startday + 1) > 0){
          $day = ($i - $startday + 1);
        }
        else{
          $day = null; //stops days from saying -1 etc
          $_date = strval($cYear) . strval($cMonth) . strval($day); //creates date from other strings
        }
        echo "<td align='center' valign='middle' height='30'> <a href='overveiw_info.php?Day=$_date' method='POST'>$day</a> </td>"; //makes the button into a link to more info
        if(($i % 7) == 6 ) echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: You're only setting `$_date` in the `else` block, not the `if` block.

Comment: `if (($i - $startday + 1) > 0)` is more clearly written as `if ($i > $startday + 1)`

Comment: `strval($day)` will be an empty string, since you just set `$day = null;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment to `$_day` should not be inside the `else` block, you need to do it for every day.

```
for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
    if (($i - $startday + 1) > 0){
      $day = ($i - $startday + 1);
    }
    else{
      $day = null; //stops days from saying -1 etc
    }
    $_date = strval($cYear) . strval($cMonth) . strval($day); //creates date from other strings
    echo "<td align='center' valign='middle' height='30'> <a href='overveiw_info.php?Day=$_date' method='POST'>$day</a> </td>"; //makes the button into a link to more info
    if(($i % 7) == 6 ) echo "</tr>";
}
```